# Paste messaging endpoint in Teams Toolkit

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I'm trying to make my first Teams App and having a hard time following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-bot).  One issue is I can't paste anything into the bot endpoint address field.  Cmd+V does nothing, and right-click doesn't work either.  Is there a way around this?  It's really annoying having to paste the long alphanumeric string from ngrok, especially since it changes every time.  I'm using VS Code 1.55.1 with Teams Toolkit extension 1.2.2.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with VS code itself and waiting for a fix from them. As a workaround use App Studio in Teams where you can copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

@Elliott B, In Bot endpoint address field right-Click action won't work,but ctrl+v is working absolutely fine.

Comment: It does not work for me.  I tried both Cmd+V and Ctrl+V.  On macOS.